Vertical Stack Layout shows white screen with MAUI map, works fine with StackLayout
If you create a blank template with the Maps controls, following instructions shared here, in MAUI on iOS like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SignalCortex.Views.MapPage"
             xmlns:maps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/maps"
             Title="MapPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <maps:Map x:Name="map"
        />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

You will see a blank white screen.
But if you change the VerticalStackLayout to just be StackLayout the maps appears fine. What am I missing here, I don't see anything in the docs explaining what I am doing wrong?
Images show the screenshots from when you run the code I shared:


Typically, with VerticalStackLayout and likely StackLayout, you need to set the HeightRequest, as they won't automatically size your component. If you prefer not to set the HeightRequest, using a Grid component might be more suitable.
